# Copying linestring attribute column to start_point end_point attribute table using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'd like to extend the [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208850/17042) proposed to [Can vector layer get start point and end point of line using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208831) and retrieve linestring attributes (columns) to the start and end points from the original object.

In the example below the Polyline object have a column [ID_Rota] that I'd like to copy to the resulting point table.

I have - so far unsuccessfully - tried to implement [@joseph's recommendation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208850/115) and add a `feat.setAttributes(feature.attributes())` with:

```
line_layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
feat = QgsFeature()

point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326", "point_layer", "memory")
pr = point_layer.dataProvider()

for feature in line_layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry().asPolyline()
    start_point = QgsPoint(geom[0])
    end_point = QgsPoint(geom[-1])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(start_point))
    pr.addFeatures([feat])
    #feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(end_point))
    #pr.addFeatures([feat])
    id_rota = feat.setAttributes(feature.attributes(ID_Rota))
    pr.addFeatures([feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```

and the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/temp/tmph65dmx.py", line 15, in <module>
    id_rota = feat.setAttributes(feature.attributes(ID_Rota))
NameError: name 'ID_Rota' is not defined
```

Comment: "ID_Rota" needs to be in quotes, like that.  See if that helps or if there are other errors too.

Comment: @alecz by taking argument with whotes I get "TypeError: QgsFeature.attributes(): too many arguments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like the following which creates another `ID_Rota` field in the point output file and copies the attribute values from the line feature:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

line_layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
feat = QgsFeature()

point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326", "point_layer", "memory")
pr = point_layer.dataProvider()
field = QgsField("ID_Rota", QVariant.Int) 
pr.addAttributes([field])
point_layer.updateFields()

for feature in line_layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry().asPolyline()
    start_point = QgsPoint(geom[0])
    end_point = QgsPoint(geom[-1])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(end_point))
    feat.setAttributes([feature["ID_Rota"]])
    pr.addFeatures([feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```

Comment: perfect! can we call additional fields in the same two lines `field = QgsField("ID_Rota", QVariant.Int)`; `field = QgsField("ID_Rota", QVariant.Int) 
pr.addAttributes([field])` or add as many lines as new fields?

Comment: @PauloCardoso - Glad it worked! Yes, `addAttributes()` requires a list of `QgsFields`. So we could just use `pr.addAttributes([QgsField("field1", QVariant.Int), QgsField("field2", QVariant.Int)])` in a single line. Then we can transfer attributes using `feat.setAttributes([feature["field1"], feature["field2"]])`.