# How to find nearest nodes of polyline in QGIS using Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have two line layers assume A and B and each layer contains multiple features.
I have selected one feature in layer A, by using that I need to find nearest nodes of a features in layer B .

I tried this

```
for rfeat in LayerA.selectedFeatures():
    rgeom = rfeat.geometry()
    geom_buffer = rgeom.buffer(50, -1)
    for feats in LayerB.getFeatures():
        sgeom = feats.geometry()
        if sgeom.intersects(geom_buffer ) :
            print(feats["id"])
```

but I am getting all features in layerB.

Comment: Yes, based on one selected feature in layerA i need to find nearest nodes of features exists in layerB.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one workflow:

1. Get selected layerA feature xy centroid coordinate ([Finding middle point (midpoint) of line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58079/finding-middle-point-midpoint-of-line-in-qgis))
2. Use xy coordinate from step 1 with `nearestNeighbor()` to get nearest featureB to featureA ([Finding nearest line to point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59173/finding-nearest-line-to-point-in-qgis))
3. Create an in-memory point layer and add nearest featureB vertex points to the in-memory point layer (not exactly but something like @Joseph answer here [Can vector layer get start point and end point of line using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208831/can-vector-layer-get-start-point-and-end-point-of-line-using-pyqgis), you'll have to iterate over the geom object)
4. Use `nearestNeighbor()` method again and featureA xy centroid coordinate to find nearest in-memory point feature

This should return the nearest feature and point vertex of featureB to featureA.

Comment: Thank you for the information , i will do step by step as you mentioned .Hope it works

Comment: Added another helpful link to step 3