# First and last point of MultiLineString-objects in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, vertices

I would like to identify the start- and endpoints within a set of polylines and return the coordinates of both points finally.

So far i have been able to iterate the features and found out that ArcGIS's export created a *MulitLineString* with a number of vertices (where the number corresponds to the length of the line).

Using `feature.geometry().vertexAt(0)` (where feature is the current feature within a for loop) returns the first point of every feature and the print-result looks like that `<QgsPoint: Point (4800744.81731882505118847 2812251.2178244274109602)>` but i didn't find a way to set up a "for vertex in vertices"-style iteration to get the last point of every line.

The Python2.x-style from [Can vector layer get start point and end point of line using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208831/can-vector-layer-get-start-point-and-end-point-of-line-using-pyqgis/208850) with

```py
geom = feature.geometry().asPolyline()
start_point = QgsPoint(geom[0])
end_point = QgsPoint(geom[-1])
```

doesn't work anymore.`asPolyline()` seems to return an empty list.

I've tried to iterate the vertices with `vertices(self) → QgsVertexIterator` but cant get any results.
since i am pretty new to PyQGIS the QGIS Python API seems really confusing to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're input is a multilinestring, then you'll need to handle that by either iterating through all the parts or (blindly!) just taking the first part alone.

**For QGIS <= 3.4:**

To take the first part:

```
multilinestring = feature.geometry().get()
first_part = multilinestring.geometryN(0)
# first_part will be a QgsLineString object
```

To get the first/last vertices:

```
first_vertex = first_part.pointN(0)
last_vertex = first_part.pointN(first_part.numPoints()-1)
```

**For QGIS > 3.4:**

The API is much easier here. You can use code like this and it'll work for BOTH linestring and multilinestring inputs:

```
for part in feature.geometry().get():
    first_vertex = part[0]
    last_vertex = part[-1]
```

Comment: I don't know why but in Qgis 3.10 this is only working for me when i use constGet() instead of get(). The api actually recommends to use constGet instead of get anyway: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsGeometry.html?highlight=qgsgeom#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.constGet

Comment: Yes, indeed works with constGet() in Qgis 3.10