# Why get the first and the last point code from a multilinestring layer in PyQGIS 3 doesn't works?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I need to get the first and the last vertex from a multilinestring layer from PostGIS and create a memory point layer with them. The code below works for some line layers and doesn't for others in QGIS 3.6 and I can't figure out why. When I run it in QGIS 3.4 it simply doesn't work and don't get any error message.

```
line_lyr = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
feat = QgsFeature()

point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:31984", "point_layer", "memory")
pr = point_layer.dataProvider()

for feature in line_lyr.getFeatures():
  geom = feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline()
    for line in geom:
      start_point = QgsPointXY(geom[0][0])
      end_point = QgsPointXY(geom[-1][-1])
      feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(start_point))
      pr.addFeatures([feat])
      feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(end_point))
      pr.addFeatures([feat])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```

I had missed something in the code? How can I improve this code for PyQGIS3?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208831/can-vector-layer-get-start-point-and-end-point-of-line-using-pyqgis

Comment: Your code should work fine for _MultiLineString_ geometry types. Did you check if all layers are of the same type? Do you receive an output if you run it in 3.4? Are there attributes stored?

Comment: @FranRaga, thanks for your comment.  I'll improve the question title, so the link you posted is related to a question about how to get the points, and I know how to get the points but I want to figure out why this code doesn't works for certain line layers and for a specific QGIS version.

Comment: @Joseph, yes this code is specific for _MultiLineString_ geometry. I'm using a PostGIS database divided in roads, streets, waterflow and duct tables all of they was set to be multilinestring geometry when I wrote the sql commands. In the 3.4 I don't get any output, but in 3.6 when I run it in roads layer I get this error: _Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
  exec(code, self.locals) File "<input>", line 1, in <module> File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a multilinestring._

Comment: @FranciscoCamello - I guess there are some null geometries in your roads layer. Try adding an if statement `if feature.geometry() is not None:` directly after the line `for feature in line_lyr.getFeatures():` and indent accordingly. This should ignore null geometries.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, the if statement works fine, but, I've run some of topology/geometry tools and I've found and correct null geometrys, even so I leave the if statement in the code. Feel free to answer the question, if you want, this way I can rate it as correct.

Comment: @FranciscoCamello - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the comments, the geometries could contain errors or be *Null*. Run geometric-reparing tools to try and fix existing errors.

Additionally, inserting the following `if` statement ignores all null geometries in the current feature and continues with the next:

```
for feature in line_lyr.getFeatures():
    if feature.geometry() is not None:
        geom = feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline()
        ...
```